# How do I save data from a variable to a file?

Tags: c#, save

So I have a method, and I want to keep track of how many times it gets called.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static int useCount;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Add(1, 3);
        Add(2, 4);
        Console.WriteLine(useCount);
    }

    public static int Add(int A, int B)
    {
        int sum = A + B;
        useCount++;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to save useCount to a file or something? In addition, if I can save it to a file, can it be updated?  Like if the useCount was 4, but then the program gets restarted, and useCount is 7, can I add that to the saved file where it shows 11, instead of overwriting the previous useCount of 4?

Hope I'm coherent enough.

Comment: You can use the ```File``` class to write to a file. A demo is available in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file). Another option if you are just saving the value for later and do not want to rely on a file is to use the ```Registry``` class (documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.setvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)), but this is a very dangerous option if you do not have experience dealing with the Registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the values into a file.
Write on the top of your program "using System.IO" to implement the library.

```
using System.IO; //implement the library of the file operations.

if(File.Exists("<Here you puth path>"))
{
int value = int.Parse(File.ReadAllText("<Here you put path>")); /* gives the current number value of on the file */
value += useCount; //adds to the current value of the file
File.WriteAllText("<Here you put path>", value.ToString()); //updates the value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use serialization.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/basic-serialization

Instead of saving a variable to a file, preferably save the state of an object to a file, which means you have to take a class approach.

You should have a class like this :

```
[Serializable]
class MyClass
{
    private int useCount;

    public int UseCount
    {
        get { return useCount; }
        set { useCount = value; }
    }

    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        useCount++;
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Note the [Serializable] annotation at the beginning

Now in your main program you can do this to save the state of your object :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var my = new MyClass();

        my.Add(5, 5);
        my.Add(5, 5);
        my.Add(5, 5);

        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream("MyFile.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        formatter.Serialize(stream, my);
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

This program will create a binary "MyFile.bin" file. You can rename it...

To recover the state of the object, you can do this on your main program :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new FileStream("MyFile.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        var obj = (MyClass)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Close();

        // Here's the proof.  
        Console.WriteLine("useCount: {0}", obj.UseCount);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The result will be 3 because you call Add method 3 times...